# python: iterate over either a list or an async generator

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

Since iterators were introduced in python, it's always been possible to not care whether you are dealing with an iterator or a list:

```
from random import random

def gen_list():
    print('gen')
    for i in range(10):
        yield i

def return_list():
    print('return')
    return [i for i in range(10)]


if random() > 0.5:
    x = gen_list()
else:
    x = return_list()

for i in x:
    pass
```

PEP 492 introduced [asynchronous iterators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#asynchronous-iterators-and-async-for) and the `async for` syntax.  What I can't see is any justification for the new burden of adding syntax to the consumer of the async iterator.

In my code, I sometimes am dealing with a list (from a cache), and sometimes with an async generator:

```
import asyncio
from random import random

def is_small_and_in_cache():
    if random() > 0.5:
        print('in fake cache')
        return [i for i in range(10)]

async def get_progressively():
    print('gen')
    for i in range(10):
        # e.g. an await here
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        yield i

async def main():
    x = is_small_and_in_cache()
    if x is None:
        x = get_progressively()

    async for i in x:
        pass

asyncio.run(main())
```

But the above fails (half the time) with `TypeError: 'async for' requires an object with __aiter__ method, got list`.

**Main Question:** How to write this so that we can deal with either?  Should I try to convert the list to a dummy async generator, or wrap the async generator so that it produces a list?

**Side Quest:** Are there any proposals to get rid of the (clearly unpythonic, to me) `async for` construct, i.e. why can't a regular `for` loop handle an asynchronous generator?  Has Python3x lost it's way in terms of usability??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax exists to **warn** you that your “loop” might actually include suspending your entire call, allowing other code to run, so that you know to have appropriate data in a consistent state at the top of each iteration.  It’s not going anywhere.

Of course, a coroutine doesn’t *have* to suspend, and you can use that to make **wrapping** any iterable trivial:

```
async def desync(it):
  for x in it: yield x
```

This is more generally useful than the opposite number which—still asynchronously, as it must—gathers into a list:

```
async def gather(ai):
  ret=[]
  async for x in ai: ret.append(x)
  return ret
```

since it allows for proper interleaving in the fully asynchronous case.

Comment: hmmm, although it's academic, `for i in await x:` would better get across this idea, as it's not the loop that relinquishes control, but the generator.  This would also better mirror the caller=>await/callee=>async of the existing async function system.

Comment: @EoghanM: `for i in await x:` already means something, though: that `x` is some awaitable (*e.g.*, a suspended asynchronous generator) that provides a whole (synchronous) iterable in one go.