# TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not subscriptable in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im trying to make a command for my discord bot that gets the message content from a specific channel without using discord.ext, I have tried putting it inside my async def on_message(message) function and it doesnt want to work. I know discord.ext will be better for this but I still want to what I have been using.
Heres my code:

```
TOKEN = 'MY_BOTS_TOKEN'
import discord
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
@client.event 
async def on_message(message):
    mychannel = client.get_channel(MYCHANNELID)
    content = (mychannel.history(limit=1))[0].content
    if message.content.startswith('.content'):
        await message.channel.send(content)
client.run(TOKEN)
```

I tried putting the `mychannel = client.get_channel(MYCHANNELID)  content = (m7channel.history(limit=1))[0].content`  into a different function and then calling onto it in `message.channel.send()`. I wasnt expecting it to work and I guessed correctly.
I also tried putting `(await mychannel.history(limit=1))[0].content)` inside of `message.channel.send()` but it returned the same error as the title.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67885961/python-iterate-over-either-a-list-or-an-async-generator

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.